# How can I trick bootstrap rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to trick bootstrap rows somehow. I need to put many col-..-.. items in only one row (there are about 8 really complicated .js files that I'm afraid of altering - and it points to children of the div that I additionally used as a bootstrap row). No way to trick the HTML, I have tried many-many ways. In case you don't believe me, check out the [specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109734/how-can-i-use-lightgalley-js-with-multiple-rows).

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHL2o.jpg)
*The red boxes are the images that I'm using and the striped space is left blank. If I align the element that is on the blank row, the next one goes there and the problem is still unsolved.

What's quite interesting that Firefox and IE show everything [the way I them to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxW8b.jpg)
but Chrome and Edge [do not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da0Pf.jpg).

Can anyone help me on this? I'm sure there must be some easy way that I missed out, like altering some of the default bootstrap row class properties, but I just couldn't get it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Look into using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead. It's designed for what you're trying to do, where Bootstrap isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved  using CSS Grid layout.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout